# Can a player be moved between leagues?

Tags: xbox-360, nhl-10

I picked up a cheap used copy of NHL 10 for Xbox 360 (missing the instruction manual), and am wondering if it's possible to move a player from one league to another. Specifically, there are a couple of players on SEL team rosters that I'd like to include on an NHL team in Season mode.

I'm a huge hockey nerd and a couple of my favourite team's draft picks that are now playing in the NHL in real life are still stuck in the SEL in the video game. Trying to get the rosters as close to accurate as I possibly can.

Comment: Did EA stop maintaining roster updates for '10 now that '11 is out and underway?

Comment: Yeah, the last roster update download is essentially from the end of last season, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you're not missing anything: the instruction book is as useless for this as it is for most EA games (you get controls and that's about it).

You need to go to My NHL 10, then Roster Management, then Player Movement. Use RB to select the SEL and RT to select the team you want. Move the stick down to find the player you want on an NHL team, press A to put him in the Moving Block and then Y to drop him to free agency.

Use LB to move back to the NHL, RT to bring up the team to which you want to add the newly-dropped player. move the stick right to get to Free Agents, down to select the player, and press A. (You may also have to move back to the left, move down to select a current NHL player to drop, and press A to move him to the Moving Block.) When the free agent is (or both players are) on the Moving Block, press X to Execute Move ... this should put the former SEL player on the NHL team.

Repeat as often as needed.